# When would it be that Ubuntu 15.XX is released?

Tags: kernel

I just bought new laptop which is Lenovo ThinkPad E455 posted on the H/W partner.

And it is found that 14.10 has kernel 3.16 which is older than currnet release.

It is wanted to know if Ubuntu 15.XX with new kernel would be released SOON

Thank you.

HELLOVENUS
Fantagio

Comment: April 23 2015 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseSchedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers here show dates.

14.10 means it was released in 2014 October, so 15.04 should be released in 2015 April.

15.10 - consequently in 2015 October.

Answer (score 0):

The next version of Ubuntu, 15.04 will be released on 23 April 2015. It will most likely feature kernel 3.18 or 3.19.